# How to get shipping address from PayPal of a particular user in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

We want to integrate paypal in our Flutter Ecommerce Store App.
It works fine if we use BrainTree but just to have a backup in case Braintree stops working or temporarily blocks its service for some reason (has happened once before), we decided to implement Paypal payment separately so the service stays running.
Now the method we found to be the most successful was by using Webview and found some good implementation here,

https://medium.com/flutter-community/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-flutter-379fbb3b87f5

**We have to calculate the tax for a person residing in USA.**

When the user logs in Paypal he/she has the option to change the shipping address. There's a method in Javascript SDK (onApprove) which has a parameter named "action" it gives that particular shipping address that the user has selected.
But we couldn't find any way to get that address in Flutter.

Can anybody tell me what can I do in this case?

(p.s for code lookup please check the link above, we've implemented the same).

Comment: For people coming from Flutter, 
I did contact PayPal support and they say their mobile sdks are depreciated so its preferred to use flutter_native_paypal (pub.dev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation at https://medium.com/flutter-community/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-flutter-379fbb3b87f5 .. uses redirects from the PayPal v1/payments API (initial create, followed by 'execute' on return). This API is deprecated, and should not be used for any new integrations.

Instead use the v2/checkout/orders API (initial create, followed by 'capture' on return). This API is current.

Regardless, after the return it is possible to do a 'GET' on the created resource which will return the selected shipping address, among other information, and allow you to present the review page (which is a required step, unless you added user_action:PAY_NOW to change the verbiage of the last button at PayPal to 'Pay Now'. Then and only then having a review step before capture is optional).

For flutter it won't specifically matter that you are using redirects, but for a general web integration redirects should be avoided, instead using [the JS SDK for approval](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/). This opens a popup window/tab for the approval
in most browsers. For a webview browser, it can be made to work by adding the following "popup bridge" module at the native app level that is displaying the webview:

- https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-ios
- https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-android

This is a module. I was created by Braintree, it does not use the Braintree service.

---

The Braintree service and PayPal are equally reliable, so implementing both for redundancy purposes is unnecessary extra work for most practical purposes. Either of the integrations is sufficient on its own.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, and yes I know the guide here on the medium's website is old (for v1) but I am not an expert developer so I couldn't find a better explanation. 
Let me try this then I'll let you know if I face some problem again. 
Cheers !!

Comment: I wasn't passing a default shipping address in transaction (creatingOrder). Therefore even if the user changes the shipping address in the PayPal review window, it doesn't show up in the show payment details Api's response.

Comment: It does actually, unless you specified NO_SHIPPING their selected address during PayPal approval is returned. This is the shipping address of the transaction.